# 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_connected'

Tags: python, discord, bots, discord.py

i have wrote a bot to play music, but  it always print and error:

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'is_connected'
```

This is my function:

```
async def play(ctx, url):
if ctx.message.author.voice:
    channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    if not voice.is_connected():
        await channel.connect()
```

I think the error is generated by this function:

```
voice.is_connected()
```

Dont know why it doesn't work ...

Comment: `voice` is returning as None. You probably need to enable intents https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/intents.html

Comment: Please verify that the variable voice is set to a valid value. It looks like it is getting None value from the error.

Comment: Try using `client.voice_client` instead of `client.voice_clients`.

Comment: If I print vonly the vocie variable it also return None, how can I fix this?

Comment: if I use client.voice_client instead of client.voice_clients I get this error:
`'Bot' object has no attribute 'voice_client'`

Comment: I have enable intents, but doesn't make a difference :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this would work

```
channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel

        voice = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.voice_channels, name=channel.name)

        voice_client = discord.utils.get(self.client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)

        if voice_client == None:
            await voice.connect()
        else:
            await voice_client.move_to(channel)
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
```

Is returning `None`, meaning that there was either nothing at all in `client.voice_clients`, or none of them matched the `guild` criteria. In this case, it's probably the former, as I'm guessing your bot is not yet connected to any voice channels, so `client.voice_clients` is empty.

Make a slight modification to account for when `voice` is `None`:

```py
    if voice is None or not voice.is_connected():
        await channel.connect()
```

Comment: Doesn't work, if I make this, I get the same error, and if I only use `voice is None` it doesn't do anything :(

Comment: You shouldn't be getting the same error; if `voice` is `None`, then it shouldn't try checking `voice.is_connected`. Are you *sure* you're getting the same error? To gain some potential insight into what's going on, try adding this immediately after your assign `voice`: `print(f'voice = {voice!r}')`. What do you get?

Comment: Also if the bot is in the voice channel I printed voice, and the output is none

Comment: Hold on, if you're using `ext.Commands`, then why do you have a `client` variable? Is `type(client)` `discord.Client` or `discord.ext.Commands.Bot`? Please update your question with the rest of your code, I'm beginning to believe that something else is at play here.

Comment: `from discord.ext import commands
import discord

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!")

`

Comment: `@client.command(name='play')
async def play(ctx, url):
    if ctx.message.author.voice:
        channel = ctx.message.author.voice.channel
        voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
        if not voice.is_connected():
            await channel.connect()
    else:
        await ctx.send(embed=Embeds.txt("No Voice Channel", "You need to be in a voice channel to use this command", ctx.message.author))
        return`

Comment: `@client.command(name='stop')
async def stop(ctx):
    voice = discord.utils.get(client.voice_clients, guild=ctx.guild)
    voice_client = ctx.message.guild.voice_client
    if voice.is_connected():
        await voice_client.disconnect()`

Comment: `client.run(TOKEN)`

Comment: @mr777 No, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/65852029/edit) to include this. This isn't what comments are for, and the code is unreadable here.